# window.clipboardData.getData("Text") doesnt work in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have this javascript function:

```
function maxLengthPaste(field,maxChars)
{
    event.returnValue=false;
    if((field.value.length + window.clipboardData.getData("Text").length) > maxChars) {
        field.value = field.value + window.clipboardData.getData("Text").substring(0, maxChars - field.value.length);
        return false;
    }
    event.returnValue=true;
}
```

The `window.clipboardData.getData("Text")` doesn't work in Chrome browser
Is there any crossbrowser code to substitute it?

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825987/in-chrome-using-the-window-clipboard-object-is-there-a-way-to-capture-pasted-t ?

Comment: Thanks Carroll.It solves the problem in chrome but Firefox can't read : `e.clipboardData.items`

Answer (score 24):

No, there is no cross-browser support for `window.clipboardData`. It is only supported by IE. Support for `window.clipboardData` is generally considered a security issue because it allows every website you visit to read whatever happens to be in your clipboard at the time.

In Chrome, you can read `clipboardData` when handling paste events:

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

Comment: I want to note `text/html` option

Answer (score 15):

**Cross browser** method should be

```
document.addEventListener('paste', function (evt) {
  clipdata = evt.clipboardData || window.clipboardData;
  console.log(clipdata.getData('text/plain'));
});
```

Comment: this worked how i wanted!! money money!! Deserve up vote :)

Comment: would like to know what is the correct (spec) way of doing it is... window.clipboardData is not even defined in chrome as null. is window.clipboardData depricated, which browser need window.clipboardData?