# window.clipboard.getdata('Text') not working in chrome

Tags: javascript

`window.clipboard.getdata('Text')` is not working in chrome. I have also tried `event.clipboard.getdata('Text')`, still no success. Can anyone please help me here how I can get data and paste it in chrome browser?

Comment: Where did you learn that code? I can't find any reference to it. There's an IE-specific `window.clipboardData.getData()`.

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30381888/1126800

Answer (score 0):

Am not sure is there such function available `clipboard`. As of my understanding there is a function which works on few of the browsers to get clipboard data that is `clipboardData`.

This will not work on page load / click events for security reasons, this can be triggered on paste event as follows, post running below code press Ctrl+v together.

```js
document.addEventListener('paste', function(evt) {
  console.log(evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain'));
});
```