# DOM: How do I get the copied text from a copy event in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, dom

I need to create a module that formats the text that a user copies from our web application. Such a module would behave something like this:

1. Intercept a `copy` event using jQuery
2. Extract the text that the user copied from the `copy` event
3. Format the text
4. Have the formatted text saved to the users clipboard

I can capture a `copy` event using the following code:

```
$("p").on("copy", function(e) {
  debugger;
});
```

When I execute this code and then copy some text and then inspect the `copy` event, I cannot find a property which contains the selected text.

I can access the [DataTransfer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer) object associated with this `copy` event by inspecting `e.originalEvent.clipboardData`, but when I do inspect it, the length of `types` array contains `0` and the `items` property is also empty.

It appears as if there is no way to access data copied to clipboard with the provided API.

There are [threads on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13825987/in-chrome-using-the-window-clipboard-object-is-there-a-way-to-capture-pasted-t) on how to handle these objects in the context of `paste` events, but how do we handle these objects in the context of `copy` events?

Answer (score 1):

After a bit of research I believe I have found a [viable solution thanks to Google Developers page](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/04/cut-and-copy-commands?hl=en).

The `copy` event is interesting because the `Event` object that is created actually has no data associated with the `copy` event itself other than the element that was being targeted. We can however use the `getSelection` method along with the [range API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range) to extract the copied text. From there you can use `document.execCommand('copy');` to transfer the modified copied text onto your OS clipboard.

```
var copyEmailBtn = document.querySelector('.js-emailcopybtn');  
copyEmailBtn.addEventListener('click', function(event) {  
  // Select the email link anchor text  
  var emailLink = document.querySelector('.js-emaillink');  
  var range = document.createRange();  
  range.selectNode(emailLink);  
  window.getSelection().addRange(range);  

  try {  
    // Now that we've selected the anchor text, execute the copy command  
    var successful = document.execCommand('copy');  
    var msg = successful ? 'successful' : 'unsuccessful';  
    console.log('Copy email command was ' + msg);  
  } catch(err) {  
    console.log('Oops, unable to copy');  
  }  

  // Remove the selections - NOTE: Should use
  // removeRange(range) when it is supported  
  window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();  
});
```